# can't print array values in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I need to generate ipset rules dynamically. so i created following script and having error try to get the urls from array.

```
#!/bin/bash

# urlList
allow_SMTP_OUT_URLS=(mtp.sendgrid.net)
allow_HTTP_OUT_URLS=(archive.mariadb.org)
allow_HTTPS_OUT_URLS=(ppa.launchpad.net repo.mongodb.org www.google.com)
allow_SSH_OUT_URLS=(bitbucket.org)

ipsetNames=(allow_HTTP_OUT allow_HTTPS_OUT allow_SMTP_OUT allow_SSH_OUT)

for ipSET in "${ipsetNames[@]}"
do

   ipset create -exist $ipSET hash:ip timeout 86400 comment family inet

   chkIPSETexsit="$(ipset list -n | grep $ipSET)"

# Check / Adding IPSET rules
   if [ -z "$chkIPSETexsit" ]; then
       echo "$ipSET is empty"
       exit 1
   else
       echo "$ipSET is present. Adding URLs to ipset"

       urlList=$ipSET
       urlList+="_URLS"

       echo "urlList: $urlList"

       echo URLs:   ${(echo $urlList)[@]}
   fi
done
```

its gives error as bad substitution

> ```
> allow_HTTP_OUT is present. Adding URLs to ipset
> urlList: allow_HTTP_OUT_URLS
> /root/salt-cron-scripts/test2.sh: line 30: ${(echo $urlList)[@]}: bad substitution
> ```

Any suggestions to correct this please

Comment: You've reached the level of data manipulation where `bash` is no longer appropriate to use. Choose a language with proper data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nameref declared with `declare -n`. This gives you a slightly better and more intuitive manipulation than using indirect parameter expansion, such as using: `${urls[@]}`, `${urls[0]}`, `${urls[5]//a/b}` etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

# urlList
allow_SMTP_OUT_URLS=(mtp.sendgrid.net)
allow_HTTP_OUT_URLS=(archive.mariadb.org)
allow_HTTPS_OUT_URLS=(ppa.launchpad.net repo.mongodb.org www.google.com)
allow_SSH_OUT_URLS=(bitbucket.org)

ipsetNames=(allow_HTTP_OUT allow_HTTPS_OUT allow_SMTP_OUT allow_SSH_OUT)

for ipSET in "${ipsetNames[@]}"
do

   ipset create -exist $ipSET hash:ip timeout 86400 comment family inet

   chkIPSETexsit="$(ipset list -n | grep $ipSET)"

# Check / Adding IPSET rules
   if [ -z "$chkIPSETexsit" ]; then
       echo "$ipSET is empty"
       exit 1
   else
       echo "$ipSET is present. Adding URLs to ipset"

       urlList=${ipSET}_URLS
       echo "urlList: $urlList"
       declare -n urls=$urlList
       echo "URLs: ${urls[@]}"

   fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation it's really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use indirect parameter expansion to expand the array named by `urlList`.

```
allow_SMTP_OUT_URLS=(mtp.sendgrid.net)
allow_HTTP_OUT_URLS=(archive.mariadb.org)
allow_HTTPS_OUT_URLS=(ppa.launchpad.net repo.mongodb.org www.google.com)
allow_SSH_OUT_URLS=(bitbucket.org)

ipsetNames=(allow_HTTP_OUT allow_HTTPS_OUT allow_SMTP_OUT allow_SSH_OUT)

for ipSET in "${ipsetNames[@]}"
do

   ipset create -exist "$ipSET" hash:ip timeout 86400 comment family inet

   chkIPSETexsit="$(ipset list -n | grep $ipSET)"

   # Check / Adding IPSET rules
   if [ -z "$chkIPSETexsit" ]; then
       echo "$ipSET is empty"
       exit 1
   fi

   echo "$ipSET is present. Adding URLs to ipset"

   urlList=${ipSET}_URLS
   echo "urlList: $urlList"
   urlList=$urlList[@]

   echo "URLs: ${!urlList}"
done
```